# how to calculuate $\int_0^ \pi \sqrt{1+x^2 \sin^2x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I was finding arc length of $y=\sin x - x \cos x$ $(0 \leq x\leq \pi)$

and I found I've to solve

$$\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1 + x^2\sin^2{x}}\, dx $$

but I have no idea about this.

I tried using $\sin^2x + \cos^2x=1$, $\sin^2x =(1-\cos 2x)/2$  but failed.

Comment: [related link on wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%7B1%2Bx%5E2sin%5E2x%7D+from+0+to+pi)

Comment: [related link of elliptic integrals on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: this is the exercise problem in thomas calculus 12'th edition 6.3. Arc Length

Comment: For what it's worth the integrand is symmetric, so we may write
$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sqrt{1+(x\sin x)^2}dx.$$

Comment: @cleo it's always a solution o tag him

Comment: Notice that the problem only asks to set up the integral and then approximate it numerically (with a graphing calculator or computer).

Comment: @user84413 Although a closed-form also would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

Since there does not seem to be a simple closed form value, I would recommend the following simple approximate method.

Let the integrand $\sqrt{1 + x^2\sin^2{x}}$ have a maximum of M and minimum of m on $[0,\pi]$. Then the following inequality holds:

$$\pi \;\text{m}<I=\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1 + x^2\sin^2{x}}\, dx<\pi\;\text{M}$$

Minimum of the integrand is obviously $\text{m}=1$. Maximum of the integrand depends on the maximum of the function $f=(x\sin x)^2$. Below is a plot of $f$:

[image: Plot of the function]

Since we are dealing with approximate calculation we take $f_{max}=3$ for sake of simplicity. (The actual value is $f_{max}=3.31...$). Thus, the maximum of the integrand is $\text{M}=2$ and we get the inequality:

$$\pi <I<2\pi$$

Now, as an estimation, we take the value of the integral to be the arithmetic mean of the upper and bottom bounds of the integral:

$$I=\frac{\pi+2\pi}{2}=\frac{3\pi}{2}=4.71...$$

The actual value of the integral is $I=4.69...$.

Of course, the fact that the estimation turned out to be so close to the actual value, is a fluke.